# ACE: multicast-join returns with success (0), but no interface is available

Tags: c++, linux, windows, multicast, ace

The challenge is to determine if the wanted "interface to use" for the multicast-socket is not available.
Currently a ACE_SOCK_Dgram_Mcast is created and join() is called with explicit interface-selection and reuse_addr == 1 (see note 1).

I would have expected that join() returns with -1 (error) or some of the other errno. But it returns with 0, even when all ethernet-adapters are unplugged (and loopback-adapter is deactivated).
I had the idea to call open() with similar parameters before doing join(), but this also works perfectly fine (returnvalue 0).

Can anyone explain this? I was expecting that join/open return a failure in case the wanted interface for Multicast is not available. And being an unplugged interface, means to me "not available".
What do I miss?

By the way: "ipconfig /all" on the Windows-terminal lists for all devices "unplugged or not available", so the wanted interface (specified by IP-address) is not listed.

**Setup:**
C++ with ACE 6.3.1-library; Win7; built as x86_32 binary - but will be later deployed as well with Ubuntu 14.04 (Linux)

**note 1:**

> int join (const ACE_INET_Addr &mcast_addr,
>   int reuse_addr = 1,               // (see above)
>   const ACE_TCHAR *net_if = 0);

Comment: The final solution needs to be discussed (internally), but the plan is to rely on **QNetworkInterface::InterfaceFlags QNetworkInterface::flags() const** from the Qt-library to check conveniently for both reference-platforms (Win7 and Ubuntu 14.04) if the interface is useable for multicast-joining.<br> It looks like **ACE** provides really no own way to provide this functionality.<br> Thank you for your attention :)

Comment: No idea, maybe you can extend one of the ACE unit tests and see what is happening? Maybe we need a small extension to ACE

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I had a look at `Multicast_Test.cpp` and searched through it. Since some "outside" modifications to the adapter would be neccessary, I withdrew from that idea to put this into a single unit-test.

Comment: The extensions have to be made to the ACE library, the test is just a way to validate the new functionality and demonstrate how to use it.